# Modifying a function to add an extra search for an specific value

Tags: r, function

With the following function, I search into a list (my_list) and returns the elements of the list that have any column with ".Positivedata"

```
#Function to give me the names of elements in a list with any column with character 
 ".Positivedata" (Works OK)


names(my_list)[sapply(my_list, function(x) any(grep(".Positivedata", names(x))))]
```

Now I would like to modify the function to return which of the names have a value of "4" on the column ".Positivedata"

## Where do I put the  "== 4"  in the function?

```
  names(my_list)[sapply(my_list, function(x) any(grep(".Positivedata", names(x))) )]
```

Comment: Try `sapply(my_list, function(x) which(x[, grep("\\.Positivedata", names(x))] == 4))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We loop through the `list`, subset the column with `grep`, check whether that is equal to 4 and use `which` to get the position

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) which(x[, grep("\\.Positivedata", names(x))] == 4))
```

---

If there are multiple columns, then it would be better to get the row/column index

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) 
    which(x[, grep("\\.Positivedata", names(x))] == 4, arr.ind = TRUE))
```

---

If we want the column name among the columns that are `.Positivedata` having the value '4'

```
sapply(my_list, function(x) {
         nm1 <- grep("\\.Positivedata", names(x), value = TRUE)
         nm1[sapply(x[nm1], function(x) any(x==4))]
         })
```

Comment: We are getting closer, but not exactly what I'm looking for. Is it possible to get only the  "names" ?. In fact, I just want the names. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Albert  `names` don't get the value of the column`.  It is not clear from the comments.  Can you please update your post with an example and expected output

Comment: @Albert I updated with a variant.  May be that is what you wanted

Comment: I think, your last variant will almost do what I'm looking for, why I'm getting the list of elements with (character(0)) below, instead of only the name of element? Again thank you for your time.

Comment: @Albert Because for that `list` element there is no `4` value for any of the columns that have name `.Positivedata`